# integration jsf and spring Exception : org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsf, jakarta-ee

I have a problem with the integration of jsf and spring, i'm a newbie to the word of Java EE and it's my first time using both of them.
I'm using netbeans 7.2 and tomcat 7
spring 3.1.1.RELEASE, JSF 2.1
I followed a tutorial on the web which is using maven; but for my case, I don't wanna use it.
so I made the same project but without the dependencies.
but I get this error `org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [services.MessageServiceImpl] for bean with name 'messageService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: services.MessageServiceImpl.`

I looked for this exception on the web, I found a lot of answers, but I didn't understand since a lot of examples are using maven.

this is my log

```
   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [services.MessageServiceImpl] for bean with name 'messageService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: services.MessageServiceImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1262)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:897)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:566)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:535)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1461)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:860)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:357)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: services.MessageServiceImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1254)
    ... 49 more

mai 13, 2014 4:48:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
   <listener>
      <listener-class>
         org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
      </listener-class>
   </listener>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>
         org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
      </listener-class>
   </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<!-- =========== FULL CONFIGURATION FILE ================================== -->

<faces-config version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd">

<application>
   <variable-resolver>
      org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver
   </variable-resolver>
</application>
 <managed-bean>
      <managed-bean-name>userData</managed-bean-name>
      <managed-bean-class>beans.UserData</managed-bean-class>
      <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
      <managed-property>
         <property-name>messageService</property-name>
         <value>#{messageService}</value>
      </managed-property>
   </managed-bean> 
</faces-config>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd/spring-spring-aop-3.1.xsd-3.1.1.RELEASE.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd/spring-spring-context-2.5.xsd-3.1.1.RELEASE.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd/spring-spring-tx-3.1.xsd-3.1.1.RELEASE.xsd
">
<bean id="messageService" 
      class="services.MessageServiceImpl">
      <property name="message" value="Hello World!" />        
   </bean>
</beans>
```

UserData.java

```
package beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import services.MessageService;

public class UserData implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private MessageService messageService;

   public MessageService getMessageService() {
      return messageService;
   }

   public void setMessageService(MessageService messageService) {
      this.messageService = messageService;
   }

   public String getGreetingMessage(){
      return messageService.getGreetingMessage();
   }
}
```

MessageService.java

```
package services;

public interface MessageService {
   String getGreetingMessage();
}
```

MessageServiceImpl.java

```
import services.MessageService;

public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService {

   private String message;

   public String getGreetingMessage() {
      return message;
   }
   public String getMessage() {
      return message;
   }
   public void setMessage(String message) {
      this.message = message;
   }
}
```

I would appreciate your help, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: services.MessageServiceImpl
```

From your code, you don't have a class `MessageServiceImpl` inside `services` package. Just move this class inside `services` package and redeploy your project.

Comment: thank your for your response, but MessageServiceImpl is already in this package but i don't know why i'm getting this error.

Comment: After fixing that problem, does the **same problem** appears. By the same problem, I mean you check the stacktrace, read it and the same error message *java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: services.MessageServiceImpl* appears.

Comment: it didn't need to be fixed, it's already fixed. the class MessageServiceImpl is inside the package services.

Comment: This is odd. Anyway, what is the new exception you're getting?

Comment: thank you for you help,i spend all day yesteday to fix it, and now it just worked , i don't know how but i changed to glassfish and ran it, and i went back to use tomcat, and it just worked :)